# my routing is not working proper in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

Here are my two routes mentioned in http/routes.php

```
Route::get('/{buy_type}-property/{type}-in-{city}/{location}/project/{projname}/{section}', 'APP\DetectHookController@detectProjectcase4')->where('projname', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+')->where('location','[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+')->where('section', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+');
```

And second one is

```
Route::get('/{buy_type}-property/{type}-in-{city}/{location}/project/{clustername}/{projname}', array( 'as' => 'project-with-cluster', 'uses' => 'APP\DetectHookController@detectProjectcase2'))->where('projname', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+')->where('location','[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+');
```

I want conditional routes based on the {section} parameter in first route.
The second one doesn't get call when it is supposed to be called as both routes are having same parameters. Can someone suggest me as I am helpless for almost a week.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-structure your route as:

```
Route::get('/{buy_type}-property/{type}-in-{city}/{location}/project/{projname}/cluster/{clustername}', array( 'as' => 'project-with-cluster', 'uses' => 'APP\DetectHookController@detectProjectcase2'))->where('projname', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+')->where('location','[A-Za-z0-9_\-A-Za-z0-9_\-]+');
```